# How to write one login form for both the admin and the user

Tags: php, select, authentication, html-table

I'm trying to write a code that takes two input values( username and password) and compare them with values in a table (named as user) in the database. Now, if the value inserted for the username is "admin" and also the password is "admin". I want to direct the admin to his page, and if the user has inserted his info, I want to direct him to his page also. My code below looks correct but I'm getting no response. How can this be fixed?

I wrote this code for html:

```
<form name="userLogin" action="LoginCode.php" method="POST" >
            <h3>Login</h3>

            <table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">Your Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
     <input  type="text" name="user_username" maxlength="50" size="30" required>
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Password *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
     <input  type="password" name="user_password" maxlength="50" size="30" required>
 </td>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </form>
```

And this is my LoginCode.php

```
<?php

include ("../Connections/map_connection.php");
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $user_username = $_POST["user_username"];
    $user_password = $_POST["user_password"];
    /* $user_email=$_POST["user_email"]; */

    if ($username = 'admin' and $user_password = 'admin') {
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name'] = $data['user_username'];
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + 400;
        header("location: ..Admin/AdminIndex.php");
    } else {
        $sql = ("select * from user where user_username='$user_username' and user_password= '$user_password' ");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error" . mysql_error();
        } else {
            $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($row == 0) {
                echo 'Invalid username or password';
            } else {
                $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['name'] = $data['user_username'];
                $_SESSION['start'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + 400;
                header("location: UserIndex.php");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this setup. Having the admin username and password both set to `admin` is one of those things...

Comment: @MariM another one of those things is storing passwords as plain text in the database. Please, never, ever do that.

Comment: Also, you use `$user_username` and `$username` sometimes interchangeably for some reason. Also you are at risk of SQL injection with how you query... Oh boy.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and nowhere do you actually run (or least show HOW you run) the query that you're trying to fetch from `$result` in.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **if** condition,

```
if ($username = 'admin' and $user_password = 'admin')
```

Here you are using single '=' i.e assignment operation instead of comparison i.e '=='.

Try this :

```
if ($username == 'admin' && $user_password == 'admin')
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::

What does this mean?

```
if ($username == 'admin' && $user_password == 'admin')
{
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ....
}
```

My point is without mysql_query() you are using mysql_fetch_assoc().

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it !!

```
<?php
    include ("../Connections/map_connection.php");
    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $user_username= $_POST["user_username"];
        $user_password= $_POST["user_password"];


        if($user_username=='admin' && $user_password){
        $sql= ("select * from admin where admin_username='$user_username' and admin_password= '$user_password' ");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            echo "Error".mysql_error();
        }
        else 
            {
             $row= mysql_num_rows($result);
             if($row==0) {
                 echo 'Invalid username or password';

        }

     else 
        {
            $data= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name'] = $data['admin_username'];
            $_SESSION['start']=time();
            $_SESSION['expire']= $_SESSION['start'] + 400;
            header("location: ../Admin/AdminIndex.php");

        }


        }
        }

        else{

        $sql= ("select * from user where user_username='$user_username' and user_password= '$user_password' ");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            echo "Error".mysql_error();
        }
        else 
            {
             $row= mysql_num_rows($result);
             if($row==0) {
                 echo 'Invalid username or password';

        }

     else 
        {
            $data= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name'] = $data['user_username'];
            $_SESSION['start']=time();
            $_SESSION['expire']= $_SESSION['start'] + 400;
            header("location: UserIndex.php");

        }


        }

        }
    }
        ?>
```